# XSS Cross Site Scripting Reflected in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, xss, cross-site

My JS file has the following code

```
function changeLanguage(newLang) {
    var winLoc = String(this.window.location);
    var pos = winLoc.indexOf("lang=");
    var spacer = '?';
    if(pos >0) {
        var curLang = winLoc.substring(pos+5,pos+7);
        winLoc = winLoc.replace('lang=' + curLang, 'lang='+newLang);

    } else {
        if(winLoc.indexOf("?") > 0) {
            spacer = '&';
        }

        winLoc = winLoc + spacer + 'lang=' + newLang;
    }

    this.window.location = winLoc;  //here is the issue


}
```

I am encountering XSS Cross Site Scripting issue at the highlighted line when scanning the code through HP Fortify Tool.

what can I do here so that HP Fortify doesn't treat this as a vulnerability? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `newLang` coming from?

Comment: @Teemu from a properties file which is stored in the project. the key value pair is  " langChangeFunction=changeLanguage('EN') "

Comment: Does it complain if you assign location using [location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) method?

Comment: That was actually barbsan's suggestion ... Anyway, setting `window.location.href` might do as well, though I'm not sure what this would have to do with XSS.

Comment: @barbsan, location.assign() worked like a charm. thanks :)

Comment: @Teemu I'd expect `window.location.href = winLoc` to raise the same XSS warning, because you have no security check using it so it might have been used by injected script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign location using [location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign). It compares origin of your script with desired url before it's assigned.
From link above:

> If the assignment can't happen because of a security violation, a `DOMException` of the `SECURITY_ERROR` type is thrown. This happens if the origin of the script calling the method is different from the origin of the page originally described by the `Location` object, mostly when the script is hosted on a different domain.

You can also use [location.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) to prevent current page from being saved in session History.